# SquirrelMail inbox blank, emails not being stored correctly

Tags: email, postfix, squirrelmail

I'm trying to set up a mail server on an Amazon EC2 Micro instance - following [this post by flurdy](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/). I've installed Postfix, Courier IMAP and Squirrel Mail. I've been testing the ability to send and receive emails via postfix - and this is working fine. I've connected to SquirrelMail succesfully - however the inbox is blank.

It appears the email files are being created at `/var/spool/mail/myuser` as opposed to `/var/spool/mail/virtual/myuser`.  At first I couldn't connect to SquirrelMail - because the myuser directory wasn't initiated within `virtual/`. So I manually added this via

```
maildirmake myuser
```

The issue now is that the emails are not being stored within `/var/spool/mail/virtual/myuser` directory, but still in `/var/spool/mail/myuser` file.

Edit > postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = mymailexample.co.uk
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Edit>
This is the result of the `concat(home,'/',maildir)` from the SQL query - You can see the mail directory ends with a slash `/`

```
/var/spool/mail/virtual/myuser/
```

Solved> 
I noticed in the mail.log there was the following>

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[16423]: warning: do not list domain mymailexample.co.uk in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
..
postfix/virtual[17251]: 149535DC7: to=, relay=virtual, delay=0.14, delays=0.12/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

I updated `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to

```
mydestination = mail.mymailexample.co.uk, localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

And it worked. Warning disappears and the logs now reveal (delivered to maildir)

```
..
postfix/virtual[17251]: 149535DC7: to=, relay=virtual, delay=0.14, delays=0.12/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
```

Comment: Please show non-verbose logs of a single message being delivered to the wrong mailbox (grep the Queue-ID.)

Answer (score 2):

[**As documented**](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox), in order to deliver in maildir format, the mailbox location **must end with a slash**:

```
joe@example.com  example.com/joe/
```

This, and this only, tells postfix to deliver to a maildir.

Of course, there could be other problems preventing it from working, but we don't know.

Comment: I've added an edit to my Question. Not sure what else it could be? But the mailbox location has the ending slash

Comment: You can start by including the output of `postconf -n` with your post.

Comment: Cheers - I've added the output..